# hg diff by specifying one revision and automatically using the parents of that particular revision

Tags: mercurial

This this possible? Currently, I first do an `hg parents` to find the parents, then an `hg diff` using two revisions. But it would be easier if `hg diff` had the option to take a single revision and find the parents automatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for the 'change' switch on diff:

```
 -c --change REV          change made by revision
```

you use it like this (for revision 298):

```
hg diff --change 298
```

If you use it on a merge changeset (which has two parents), only the first parent is compared. In that case you can use the `p2` [revset](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/revsets) to get the second parent:

```
hg diff -r 298:p2(298)
```

Answer (score 2):

```sh
hg diff -r 'tip~1'
```

because

> "x~n"
> The nth first ancestor of x; "x~0" is x; "x~3" is "x^^^". For n < 0, the nth unambiguous descendent of x.